# HTTP Response Header Regex

Tags: regex, http-headers, jmeter, httpresponse

I had planned to use Jmeter Regex Extractor to get a Session ID in HTTP Response Header. This is the example of the HTTP Header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: yoke
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,DELETE,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,jsessionid,Origin,Accept,Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Size,Message,Total-Pages,Total-Count,Current-Page,jsessionid,Origin,Total-Outstanding,Content-Range
content-type: application/json
jsessionid: 10838d69-f9ac-4c70-b1f7-9447a7a6a463
Content-Length: 106
```

All I need to get is :

```
10838d69-f9ac-4c70-b1f7-9447a7a6a463
```

I use this REGEX :

```
jsessionid: [^\n]+
```

But I get :

```
jsessionid: 10838d69-f9ac-4c70-b1f7-9447a7a6a463
```

Can you help me with it?
Thank you

Best Regards,
Stefio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex expression

```
jsessionid: ([^\n]+)
```

and Template

```
$1$
```

Your issue has to do with regex grouping.  Group 0 is the entire match, which is the default of Jmeter Regex Extractor.  Group 1 is what was matched by the regex inside the first set of parenthesis.  Template $1$ says to use the contents of group 1 as your result.  Regex grouping can get much more complicated, so read tutorials if you want to grab multiple values from a regex expression.
[Jmeter Regex Extractor user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: the regular expression above works on my jmeter. Thank you chris.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `lookaround` for regex, for you particular case it'd be lookbehind regex. This outght to work, untested though:

```
(?<=jsessionid:\s).+
```

The `(?<=jsessionid:\s)` part means literraly match `jsessionid:` but don't include it in results

Comment: The above one also selects the new line character me.  So tried this  `(?<=jsessionid:\s)[^\s]+`

Comment: this is works when I need to search the HTTP Header value (with notepad++ for example). Unfortunately, Regex Extractor Jmeter cannot find the specific response header value.

Answer (score 0):

[JSESSIONID](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html) is basically a cookie so I don't think you need to extract it with regex.

I can think of 2 scenarios why you might need it:

1. You need to pass it with the next request as a header
2. You need its value for something else

In both cases you can use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar)

- For the 1st option: it handles cookies automatically
- For the 2nd option: given `CookieManager.save.cookies` property set to `true` you should be able to access the cookie value as `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}`